# Is every finitely generated simple group $2$-generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, simple-groups

Is every finitely generated simple group $2$-generated?

This happens to be true for finite simple groups and for Tarski monster groups, but is it true in general? I do not know how to prove that, but neither do I know any counterexamples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't read it thoroughly enough to understand the construction, but this 1986 [paper by Guba](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00969195?LI=true) constructs a finitely generated simple group all of whose $2$-generated subgroups are free, and which is therefore not itself $2$-generated. From the introduction it seems that the question you asked was open until then.

Comment: That's a really cool result. The construction seems to be a bit ugly though.